# How to show checkbox as checked in update using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an attribute called IsActive and it's bool. I use checkbox to get this value. (If checkbox is checked it means that record is active but if it's not it is not active. When user wants to update the record, I get the record with a method called getrecordbyId. Everything works fine I get all the values true but if the record is active I want to show user that the checkbox as checked in update view. What should I add to show the active record as checked on my checkbox?

**My Controller**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id)
        {
            var viewModel = await _mediator.Send(new GetRecordById { Id = id });
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

**UpdateView**

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="IsActive">IsActive</label>
        <input data-val="true"
               data-val-required="The isActive field is required."
               id="IsActive"
               name="IsActive"
               type="checkbox"
               value=true />
        <span asp-validation-for="IsActive" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `checked="@viewModel.IsActive"` and it will works like charm.

Comment: Actually when I change <input> into  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive); it also works as well but thank you